# Want to run first form only once after installtion

Tags: c#, winforms

I have my first form which is taking path of folder and saving that value in user properties and opening the second form. I want to run first form only first time after installation and save that value and don't want to run that form after that. After that I want only second form to run.

This is the code of my first form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string Source = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
    Properties.Settings.Default.path = Source;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Change the Main() method in Program.cs, it determines which form gets displayed first.  Do beware of code like this, pretty easy to snooker a user with a hard-to-answer but critical first question.  If you can count on a knowledgeable admin distributing your app then change the setting's scope from User to Application so the admin can edit the path.  If not then consider an Options menu item or simply preserving the last-used path.  Note that SaveFileDialog already does that automatically.

Comment: i don't want my first form to run everytime i run the application

Comment: That was already clear.  What is not is why you don't want to put the code in the right place.  You are not stuck with the auto-generated Main() method, changing it is fine.

Comment: can you explain with example?

Comment: I can't reasonably show you a bad practice, sorry.  Just try it, you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this n it worked..

```
       static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
       if(Properties.Settings.Default.path == "" )

        {
            Application.Run(new FolderSetting());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It should go in the program.cs main() i am writing the exact code atm

Comment: after insatlling exe file the first form will run only once??

Comment: Yes you can test this with run without debugging

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default.path))      
  {
     folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
     string Source = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
     Properties.Settings.Default.path = Source;
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  }

  Form1 f = new Form1();
  f.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **registry entry** for your app  to make sure first time form is shown only once. On app start create the key if not exists. Set the key value on the first time form is opened. On each button click open the other form based on the key value set.

By setting the key in registry, you can also give configuration in the app to reset the value if user wish to do so.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software",true);

key.CreateSubKey("YourAppName");
key = key.OpenSubKey("YourAppName", true);


key.CreateSubKey("FirstTimeFlag");
key = key.OpenSubKey("FirstTimeFlag", true);

// set the key first time
key.SetValue("FirstTimeFlag", "true");

// get Value of key (probably assign this to App Constant)  
var isFirstTimeLogin = (bool)key.GetValue("FirstTimeFlag");
```

Comment: where to write this??

Comment: on main form load event [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in program.cs instead of button click. You should determine if the value of the path is blank only then open folder browser dialog to select the path otherwise directly run your second form. Your code should be like below:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.path.trim() == "")
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string Source = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
    Properties.Settings.Default.path = Source;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Show();
```

Hope it will solve your problem.